# Unexpected Behavior of a MOSFET Two Stage Differential Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, cmos

Trying to come-up with a basic default MOSFET-transistor amplifier simulation (for educational purposes). I don't get something. In the simulation below "out" is -1.84V while I expect something more like -0.5V. Also the output doesn't change when I sweep R_in. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: FET source terminal is normally tied to the body. Most everything looks upside down.

Comment: If you forget Pch drain goes towards the high side (Positive) Then for giggles make Rf from 1K to 1M with 1mV +/- square wave input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All NMOS transistors in your diagram need to be PMOS, and all PMOS transistors need to be NMOS.

Perhaps you mistook the symbol arrows? Please note that the direction of the arrow is different when you draw it on the source pin or the bulk pin.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I was P/N confused and I also had to properly size the transistors and add the manufacturers library.